# Definition of a diagram in a category

Tags: category-theory

Perhaps we know what a diagram(like a commutative diagram) in a category is.
I would like to know a definition of it.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagram_%28category_theory%29) wiki got a nice article, hope that will help.

Comment: The article says a diagram is just a functor.
While this makes sense, my hunch is that there is a different definition of a diagram.

Comment: @Makoto: Some authors require the index category to be small, but in any case this is the definition most usually seen (in my experience with category theory texts). There *is* another definition, where the index category is just a graph, see [this article on nlab](http://nlab.mathforge.org/nlab/show/diagram). I believe I recall this to be the approach taken in Barr & Wells. I can tell you nothing more about it, as I never really bothered looking into it.

Comment: @BrunoStonek How about defining a diagram as a (small) subcategory or something like that?
As the Wikipedia article says, the actual objects and morphisms in the index category are largely irrelevant, only the way in which they are interrelated matters.

Comment: @Makoto Kato, I know nothing more than that Functor definition. But could please explain why you want to study about this, I mean where this arised? I want to learn more Cat. theory but I couldn't find motivation to study or where to start, more over in my dept. there are no Cat. Theory experts.

Comment: Dear Ram, I just would like to know a *right* definition of a diagram.
As the Wikipedia article implies, it seems that the index category is largely irrelevant in defining a diagram.

Comment: @MakotoKato That _is_ the correct definition of diagram. Wikipedia is incorrect in saying that the index category is irrelevant, and your idea of defining it as a subcategory also does not work. (The functor associated to a diagram need not be injective or even faithful.)

Comment: @ZhenLin Let $X \rightarrow Y$ be a morphism in a category $\mathcal{C}$.
Suppose we would like to consider it as a diagram.
Let $I$ be a category consisting of $4$ objects and $2$ arrows.
There exists an obvious functor $F\colon I \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$.
I don't see why we should consider $F$ as a diagram representing $X \rightarrow Y$.

Comment: No, of course not. The diagram $X \to Y$ corresponds to a functor $F : \mathbb{2} \to \mathcal{C}$, where $\mathbb{2}$ is the category with two objects and one non-identity morphism. Open any good category theory textbook and you will see why this is a reasonable definition.

Comment: @ZhenLin But the above $F\colon I \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ is also a diagram in the above definition.

Comment: Sure. It corresponds to a different diagram, namely one with fourth vertices and two arrows. The shape of the diagram is the shape of the indexing category and vice-versa.

Comment: @ZhenLin My point is that the usual definition of a diagram contains largely irrelevant information. For example, $F$ needs not satisfy $F(gf) = F(g)F(f)$. What matters in most cases is the image of $F$.

Comment: I don't agree. Let us suppose we have an endomorphism $X \to X$. Then $X \to X$ and $X ↺$ are two different diagrams. They even have different (co)limits. In some textbooks you will find an extremely general definition of diagram as a certain kind of homomorphism from a certain kind of graph, but I have never found a use for that.

Comment: @ZhenLin What do you mean by X and a circle(I don't know how to write it in Latex)? By the way, please write my name at the top of your comment. Otherwise I may not notice it.

Comment: @Makoto I mean a diagram with one vertex and one non-identity arrow.

Comment: @ZhenLin I said "in most cases". If you need a limit, you should of course use a functor.

Comment: @ZhenLin A category can be regarded as a quiver(please see the Wikipedia for the definition). *One* definition of a diagram in a category may be that it is a subquiver of the category.

Comment: @MakotoKato Wikipedia says:"The actual objects and morphisms in J are largely irrelevant, only the way in which they are interrelated matters". This simply means that the actual  *names* of objects and morphisms are irrelevant (of course), but the interrelations matter. This is a common theme in CT. I think you confuse the "diagram" which is a functor with its image in the codomain category. It is true that the image counts more, but we still need the functor so that we can compose functors (and -in a sense- transfer the diagrams) and find if and how limits are preserved or created.

Comment: @magma I'm not confusing a functor with its image. I'm saying that there may be a different(and useful) definition of a diagram other than the usual one. I'm not denying using a functor.

Comment: @Makoto I don't agree with any definition that says that a diagram is necessarily a _substructure_ of a category. Like it or not, _diagram_ is now a technical word in category theory, and it is a synonym for functor.

Comment: @MakotoKato CWM 2nd ed. page 71 gives an alternative definition:diagram in C of shape G is a morphism $D : G\to UC$ of graphs.

Comment: @ZhenLin I'm not proposing to change the current terminology "diagram" as a functor. We can call a subquiver of a category a "static diagram" for example. We can choose whatever name we think appropriate for it. What really matters here is the notion, not the name.

Comment: @MakotoKato, You asked for a definition of diagram. You got one, the one used by pretty much everyone. Now, it seems that you do not like this definition... Either provide a definition for what a diagram is for you ands then ask for a definition for *that* (and, sure, this would be rather stupid...) or... well, I do not see any other option. **In any case, this discussion has clearly stopped being useful.** Start a chat room and debate there.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I already provided another definition of a diagram. ZhenLin disagreed with it. So the discussion is not over.

Comment: As you know well, *this is not a site for discussions*. You asked for a definition of diagrams and you got the standard one (which you of course knew well...) But obviously the point of your question was not asking for the definition of diagram but debating it or something. **That is off-topic**. You are free to engage anyone who wants to be engaged in a discussion about what you feel should be the definition of diagrams **elsewhere**.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I don't particularly want to discuss it. Since ZhenLin didn't answer, it's unlikely that there will be further discussion. However, someone may want to post his opinion. I don't think it's a good idea to suppress it.